# Register URL scheme handler for all users in mac

Tags: cocoa, url-scheme, launch-services

I registered a custom URL scheme (myscheme://) for my Cocoa application with the below code:

```
-(void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
CFStringRef bundleId = (__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme(CFSTR("myscheme"), bundleId);
[[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
}
```

When I install the application, it does register the URL scheme for that user and able to open via Safari browser like myscheme://abcd.

When I switch to different user and tried the same scenario, I am not able to open the URL scheme and it fails to with this message:

> Unable to find the application for the URI myscheme://abcd

Is there any additional registration to be done for registering the URL schemes for all users?

Thanks

Comment: I certainly hope it's not allowed by OS X. I don't want user X installing an app that leaks its behavior into user Y's account.

Comment: I am trying to act as an agent app where the user launches my app via the web page. The Web link in the web page internally calls the URL scheme. This is similar to how Apple apps are identified like itunes, facetime,etc when launched from web browser. I know those are Apple supported apps but wil they allow 3rd party apps in the same way?

Comment: But how would user Y open your app with the URL scheme if they didn't install your app first? If only user X has installed your app, user Y can't use the URL scheme. And that's a good thing. :) Or did I misunderstood what you're talking about? It works for Apple's apps because they are already installed in all user accounts.

Comment: My app gets installed for all user accounts by default.

Comment: I install it under /Applications folder which will be visible to all users.

Comment: So, if the app is visible to all users... how did *one* user get the scheme and not the others? I mean, how did OS X choose *which* user should benefit from the scheme, and the others should not? ;) You should really provide more context and details about what you did and how you did it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes thats my confusion. In brief, I launch the app once during app installation(Using pkg mode of installation) and open the app when it completes. Once launched, the above mentioned delegate "applicationWillFInishLaunching" will be called wherein it registers the Event handler and default URL handler (refer the above code in desc). But somehow it is only reflecting for the current user whoever installs

Comment: And that's normal. Actions from user X modifying the system (adding a scheme is a modification) should never have side-effects on other users account. In your case, each user has to open the app to register the scheme himself (unless I'm wrong, then I will be happy if someone else corrects me).

Comment: I think Eric's right. My first thought was that you may have to launch the app at least once as the other user before it'll take. I think it's an issue with the LaunchServices database. If this is the case, I encourage you to file a bug with Apple, since an app installed for all users should be properly registered for all users if for any.

Comment: Specifically (was running out of room), it seems as though LaunchServices improperly notes the capabilities/claims of the app in the user's local copy but it should trickle into all users so it it immediately honors claims for all users on that system if the app is installed in /Applications (or any other public apps folder).